# Is it possible to still make win CE 5.0 applications

Tags: windows-ce

Is it even possible - without it being a labrinthian process to devlope applications for CE 5.0? I have VS 2012 Premium. Also if I download the 5.0 SDK during the install it claims I do not have the reight environment and the link to MS is no longer valid.I am stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is still very possible, just not with the latest development tool.

Visual Studio 2008 Professional or better (not Standard, not Express) is the last set of tools that Microsoft shipped that had compilers, etc for Windows CE.  It can target CE 5.0, 6.0 and 7.0 (maybe 4.x as well, but it's been a long time since I used one, so I'm not certain).

Studio 2012 will never support those older CE OSes.  It will support the newest incarnation of CE, dubbed "Windows Embedded Compact 2013", when it comes out later this year.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that VS 2012 supports CE5. I know that VS 2005 aka VC8 supports CE, as does Platform Builder 5 (the CE building toolkit) and maybe eVC4. I guess you can get VS 2005 relatively cheap, maybe your VS 2012 license even allows you to install it without any additional cost. When buying something, take care that not every VS version supports everything, cheap student versions might not support CE.